# (Cross platform) check a file path is absolute without using Pathname library

Tags: ruby, file, cross-platform

I need a cross platform way to check if a given file path is absolute *without* using the `Pathname` library. The only library I'd wish to rely on for this would be `File`. It needs to be cross-platform and cross-implementation, so it should work regardless of it being Ruby MRI, JRuby, Rubinius… etc.

I wish to use pure Ruby, no C or Java. I can't think of a robust way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def absolute_path?(path)
  File.expand_path(path) == path
end
```